Use regex to get a list of all values in double quotes and true and false which dont have quotes?
How can I use regex to get a list of all values in double quotes and true and false which dont have quotes?
For example:
string = '"hi you, sir", True False, "come, here"'

to
lst = ["hi you, sir", True, False, "come, here"]

with 4 elements. I know i can use re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', string) to find all values in quotation but it doesnt bring out true and false as an element

lst = ["hi you, sir", true, false, "come, here"] is not valid in Python. You probably want ['hi you, sir', True, False, 'come, here']? Do you only have true and false as lowercase? If you also have True and False or TRUE, you can use p = r'(?i)"([^"]+)"|(true|false)'

You can use r'"([^"]+)"|(true|false)':
import re

s = '"hi you, sir", true, false, "come, here"'
p = r'"([^"]+)"|(true|false)'

matches = re.findall(p, s)
print([m[0] if m[0] else m[1] for m in matches])


Prints
['hi you, sir', 'true', 'false', 'come, here']


If you don't want the true and false as strings:
import re


def get_substr(s, p):
    matches = re.findall(p, s)
    res = []
    for sub, tf in matches:
        if sub:
            res.append(sub)
        if tf == 'true':
            res.append(True)
        if tf == 'false':
            res.append(False)
    return res


s = '"hi you, sir", true, false, "come, here"'
p = r'"([^"]+)"|(true|false)'

print(get_substr(s, p))

Prints
['hi you, sir', True, False, 'come, here']

